# TypeScript Error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: typescript, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on crud operations on Next.js by using Typescript.
Also Redux is implemented to the project.

This is my [id].tsx file to edit the data.

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch<ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>>();
 const category = useSelector((state:any) => state.category.categorySelected[0]);

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        dispatch(updateCategory(data));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCategoryById({ id: parseFloat(router.query.id ) }));
        if (category) {
            setValue("id", category.id);
            setValue("name", category.name);
        }
    }, [JSON.stringify(category)]);
```

In here,data that inside of the `updateCategory(data)` is giving the error.

Also,`{ id: parseFloat(router.query.id ) }` part is the giving the same error too.

categorySlice.js file:

```
export const updateCategory = createAsyncThunk("category/updateCategory", async (item, ) => {
    return axios.put(`${process.env.baseSite}/api/category/update`, item).then((response) => {
        Router.push("/admin/category");
    });
});

export const getCategoryById = createAsyncThunk("category/getCategoryById", async (item) => {
    return axios.post(`${process.env.baseSite}/api/category/getByIdCategory`, item).then((response) => {
        return response.data;
    });
});
```

Thanks.

I tried giving type by using interface  but i couldn't have any results.

Comment: `updateCategory` and `getCategoryById` are not function?

Comment: They are slices which is coming from redux store.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with your `updateCategory` and `getCategoryById` actions. Are you *sure* the issue is with them? I suspect the issue might be this `ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>` type you've specified for `useDispatch`, e.g. it's not expecting this. You normally don't need to do this sort of typing of the `useDispatch` hook. Can you [edit] to include the complete error message and any additional typescript details and information?